# Difficulties with simple ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm an absolute beginner at R, so please excuse the simplicity of this question. I'm having trouble loading a file in R and making a histogram plot from a column of data. Here's my code:

```
library('ggplot2')
df <- read.csv('/PATH/TO/FILE', sep=' ', head=FALSE)
vals <- df[,2]
qplot(df, data=vals, geom="histogram")

Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric
```

Can anyone show me what the problem is? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You are asking `qplot` to plot two data frames, i.e. `df` and `vals`. You need to remove one of these.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works with qplot. When I try the same thing with ggplot, `ggplot(vals) + geom_histogram()`. I still get errors. Do  you know what the problem could be?

Comment: Yes, when you use `ggplot` you need to specify the aesthetics with `aes()`

Comment: So, `ggplot(vals,aes(x=vals)) + geom_histogram()`? Maybe I don't quite understand, as this doesnt seem to work.

Comment: `ggplot(df, aes(x=vals)) + geom_histogram()` looks more likely.

Comment: Have you tried replicating (all of) the results of histograms documented here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_histogram.html ?

Answer (score 9):

If you need frequency histogram, try this code:

```
ggplot() + aes(vals)+ geom_histogram(binwidth=1, colour="black", fill="white")
```